# scipy.signal.cwt is getting a value error in correlate()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wavelet-transform

I'm getting a weird error when attempting to use scipy.signal.cwt:

I have some list `c`, and I want to take the continuous wavelet transform like this:

```
scipy.signal.cwt(np.array(c), scipy.signal.morlet, np.arange(.01,.1,.01))
```

and I get a weird error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-5af5e14b96cd> in <module>()
----> 1 sig.cwt(a, sig.morlet, np.arange(.01,.1,.01))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/wavelets.pyc in cwt(data, wavelet,     widths)
    359         wavelet_data = wavelet(min(10 * width, len(data)), width)
    360         output[ind, :] = convolve(data, wavelet_data,
--> 361                                               mode='same')
    362     return output

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.pyc in convolve(in1,     in2, mode)
    270 
    271     if np.iscomplexobj(kernel):
--> 272         return correlate(volume, kernel[slice_obj].conj(), mode)
    273     else:
    274         return correlate(volume, kernel[slice_obj], mode)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.pyc in correlate(in1, in2, mode)
    129         in1zpadded = np.zeros(ps, in1.dtype)
    130         sc = [slice(0, i) for i in in1.shape]
--> 131         in1zpadded[sc] = in1.copy()
    132 
    133         if mode == 'full':

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (66467) into shape (66466)
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: scipy.signal.morlet is not compatible with scipy.signal.cwt http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18104/29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the third argument of `scipy.signal.cwt` is widths, which must larger than 1, so change your code to:

```
scipy.signal.cwt(np.array(c), scipy.signal.morlet, np.arange(.01,.1,.01) * len(c))
```